# Make bibliography numbers on document look smaller

Tags: bibliographies

Using `chapterbib` for bibliographies for each chapter, how do I change the configuration file of `chapterbib` to make the numbers on my output file look as superscript (smaller size I want).
Anyone got any idea?

Example :

> This is some text taken from a reference[2], and this is how latex
>   makes it look. [2], reference X by …..

This is some text taken from a reference`\superscript[2]`, and this is how I want it to look like.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you considered loading the `natbib` citation management package with the `super` option, i.e., employing the instruction `\usepackage[super]{natbib}`?

Comment: I had not, but i just tried it and it works, thanks. Except that i have also footnotes which now look just like the bibliography links, is there a way to put the superscript between brackets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To force citation callouts to be typeset in superscript numeric mode, with square brackets surrounding the callout, load the `natbib` package with *both* the `super` and `square` options:

```
\usepackage[super,square]{natbib}
```

Of course, this presupposes that you're using a bibliography style that's compatible with numeric-style citations. Many of the "standard" bibliography styles are, fortunately, compatible with this citation mode

Comment: This works, apparently if i had read the natbib documentation i would have known my answer without having to bother you.
Thank you very much, it is what i was looking for.